# Converting string variables to number in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code in NetLogo and I am trying to convert the variables lat and long to numbers because setxy accepts only numbers:

```
to go

 if file-at-end? [ stop ]
 set data csv:from-row file-read-line

 let lat item 1 data
 let lng item 2 data
 move-turt lat lng   
 tick
end

to move-turt [lat lng]
 print lat
 ask turtles[setxy lat lng]

end
```

I tried to use read-from-strings but it didn't work and I couldn't find anything in the dictionary.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a few rows of the .csv, or just explain what format the lat and long are in right now? `csv:from-row` should automatically read numbers as numbers- do you have non-numeric characters in the lat or long fields?

Comment: @LukeC you are right i had a row with string values that i forgot about that was the problem. Thank you